# Access a Mac and PC from one KB/Mouse with 3 monitors?

Tags: windows, macos

I am a web designer and gamer using a Windows environment. I want to add a mac to my setup (perhaps a mac mini) to take advantage of many of the new gui applications like: codekit, git tower, I am a very visual person.

My current PC setup (custom):

- Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 930  @ 2.80GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.8GHz
- 24GB RAM (I know it's overkill)
- 2 X NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460 2GB (SLI)
- 3 DVI Monitors

I use a HP Media Server to backup this machine along with 2 laptops in the house. I love this setup and don't want to loose it if possible.

Is there a way for me to connect a Mac to my current setup and easily switch between the two while only using 1 keyboard, 1 mouse. Preferably I would like to use the benefit of my 3 monitors with both?

Comment: See: [Do KVMs exist for multiple monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/22160/do-kvms-exist-for-multiple-monitors)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way for me to connect a Mac to my current setup and easily switch between the two while only using 1 keyboard, 1 mouse. Preferably I would like to use the benefit of my 3 monitors with both?

I can answer this part of your question.  If you are looking for a free solution to this you can try [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/).  It allows you to share you keyboard and mouse across computers without a physical KVM switch.  In the scenario you can have you keyboard and mouse attached to your PC and then share them with the mac mini using synergy.  You would still have to then manually switch whatever monitor(s) are connected to the mac mini.  Alternatively (and probably a bit simpler) would be t

As for using all 3 monitors with the mac-mini, it has only 1 HDMI out but apparently there is an adapter to support dual monitors (not 3).  I suppose for 3 you would be looking at some sort of external display adapter to use for the 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that.
You will need a [USB DVI KVM](http://www.google.com/search?q=usb+dvi+kvm&tbm=shop) that will allow you to switch monitor and mouse/keyboard between the Mac and a PC.

[Here is one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00180H41O) that [looks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLIefeJPp40) nice

Comment: But have only **one** DVI input